# Concatenar cadenas separando cada cadena con espacios

Tags: c++

Este es el código que me da los nombres todos juntos ¿Qué podría hacer para que tenga espacios el resultado final?

```
cout << "Ingresa tu primer nombre: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Ingresa tu Primer apellido: " << endl;
cin >> name1;
cout << "Ingresa tu segundo apellido: " << endl;
cin >> name2;
sum = name + name1+ name2;
mus = name1 + name2 + name;
cout << "Tu nombre completo es: " << sum << endl;
cout << "Tu nombre completo es: " << mus << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Añade el espacio al concatenar `name + " " + name1 + " "`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta concatenar los espacios en blanco que quieras. Tendrías que cambiar tu código a lo siguiente si quietes los espacios en blanco entre el nombre y los apellidos:

```
cout << "Ingresa tu primer nombre: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Ingresa tu Primer apellido: " << endl;
cin >> name1;
cout << "Ingresa tu segundo apellido: " << endl;
cin >> name2;
sum = name + " " + name1 + " " + name2;
mus = name1 + " " + name2 + " " + name;
cout << "Tu nombre completo es: " << sum << endl;
cout << "Tu nombre completo es: " << mus << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Te lo imprime todo junto porque no hay espacios entre cada una de las cadenas. Imagina que introduzco los siguientes datos: `Pepe`, `Gafe`, `Capa`. En memoria tendrán el siguiente aspecto:

| Posición 0 | Posición 1 | Posición 2 | Posición 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | e | p | e |
| G | a | f | e |
| C | a | p | a |

Por lo que si concatenas (que se hace con el operador `+` si usamos cadenas):

```
sum = name + name1 + name2;
```

El resultado será:

| Posición 0 | Posición 1 | Posición 2 | Posición 3 | Posición 4 | Posición 5 | Posición 6 | Posición 7 | Posición 8 | Posición 9 | Posición 10 | Posición 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | e | p | e | G | a | f | e | C | a | p | a |

Si quieres que haya algún carácter entre cada cadena, tendrás que ponerlo:

```
sum = name + ' ' + name1 + ' ' + name2;
//            ^             ^
//         espacio entre cadenas
```